# Inheritance XmlSerializer C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, xmlserializer

I have these 3 classes:

```
Class Image : Asset
Class Sound : Asset
Class Video : Asset
```

everything serializes ok but when i create this item:

```
Class Master
List<Asset> assets //property
```

an instance of this class for example:

```
Image i = new Image();
Sound s = new Sound();
Video v = new Video();
Master m =  new Master( new List<Asset>{i,s,v} )
```

it does not serialize with exception 
"InvalidOperationException-There was an error generating the XML document" 
and in the innerException : {"The type MyApplication.Video was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}

.. any idea??

Comment: you could help with the exception info

Comment: Did you add the <Serializeable()> Attribute to your class? Does the Image class contains any filereader? Do you marked all nonserializeable member with the NonSerialized Attribute?

Comment: each one of the Image, Sound, Video instances serializes ok without the Serializeable attribute no the image does not contain filereader..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `XmlInclude` attribute on the `Asset` class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Video))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Sound))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Image))]
public class Asset
{
    ...
}
```